# Dynamically add object value to div inside <p> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object

On click of a button, I want to add a p tag to an existing div with the value of an object property name inside of it.

```
  var foodLoads = {
    orange: 6.7,
    apple: 5.6,
    banana: 12.7,
    grapes: 16.3,
    peach: 2.7,
    pear: 6.5,
    mango: 16.1,
    blueberries: 9.3,
    grapefruit: 1.7,
    strawberry: 3.5,
    tangerine: 3.1,
    watermelon: 8,
    duck: 0,
    beef: 0,
    chicken: 0,
    ham: 0,
    turkey: 0,
    elk: 0,
    pork: 0,
    fish: 0,
    eggs: 0,
    lamb: 0,
    applejuice: 11.8,
    cranberryjuice: 23.3,
    orangejuice: 14.4,
    carrotjuice: 8.6,
    lemonade: 24.3,
    hotchocolatemix: 10.2,
    tomatojuice: 3.5,
    chocolatemilk: 13.3,
    almondmilk: 0.02,
    soymilk: 4,
    wholewheatbread: 6.1,
    whitebread: 10.7,
    bagel: 30,
    waffle: 13.8,
    pancake: 5.3,
    croissant: 12.2,
    muffin: 28.8,
    englishmuffin: 21.3,
    doughnut: 15.2,
    oatmeal: 12.6,
    quinoa: 20.4,
    wholegrainbread: 7.1 
  }
```

The divs are created dynamically when a user checks a checkbox (this is before they click the button).

```
  $('input').on('ifChecked', function(event) {       
    var liText = $(this).parent().parent().text();
    var wrappedUp = $('<div class="active"><li>' + liText + '</li><select class="serving-size"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option></select></div>');
    $('.food-list').append(wrappedUp);
    $(wrappedUp).addClass('' + liText + '');        
})
```

This is an example of the divs I'm talking about

```
<ul class="food-list">

    <div class="active Mango">
                 <li>Mango</li>
          <select class="serving-size"><option value="1">1</option><optionvalue="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option>
          </select>
    </div>
</ul>
```

So, basically, on click of a button I want to be able to use the class (i.e. Mango) to match it with the property in the foodLoads object with the same name (mango), put that property's value in a p tag, and add it to the div with the matching class (Mango).

This is the jQuery I was trying to use. As I am new to jQuery I'm sure the syntax is all screwed up.

```
  $('.submit-items').click(function() {
    $.each( foodLoads, function( key, value ) {
      if ($('.active:contains(' + key + ')')) {
        $(this).append('<p>' + key + '</li>');
      }
})

     })
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simpler approach.

- find the text of the `li` from the `active` class.
- look up its value.
- append the `p`

like:-

```
$('.submit-items').click(function() {
   var type = $('.food-list .active li').text();
   var value = foodLoads[type.toLowerCase()];
   $('.' + type).append('<p>' + value + '</p>');
});
```

Demo

```js
var foodLoads = {
  orange: 6.7,
  apple: 5.6,
  banana: 12.7,
  grapes: 16.3,
  peach: 2.7,
  pear: 6.5,
  mango: 16.1,
  blueberries: 9.3,
  grapefruit: 1.7,
  strawberry: 3.5,
  tangerine: 3.1,
  watermelon: 8,
  duck: 0,
  beef: 0,
  chicken: 0,
  ham: 0,
  turkey: 0,
  elk: 0,
  pork: 0,
  fish: 0,
  eggs: 0,
  lamb: 0,
  applejuice: 11.8,
  cranberryjuice: 23.3,
  orangejuice: 14.4,
  carrotjuice: 8.6,
  lemonade: 24.3,
  hotchocolatemix: 10.2,
  tomatojuice: 3.5,
  chocolatemilk: 13.3,
  almondmilk: 0.02,
  soymilk: 4,
  wholewheatbread: 6.1,
  whitebread: 10.7,
  bagel: 30,
  waffle: 13.8,
  pancake: 5.3,
  croissant: 12.2,
  muffin: 28.8,
  englishmuffin: 21.3,
  doughnut: 15.2,
  oatmeal: 12.6,
  quinoa: 20.4,
  wholegrainbread: 7.1
};

$('.submit-items').click(function() {
  var type = $('.food-list .active li').text();
  var value = foodLoads[type.toLowerCase()];
  $('.' + type).append('<p>' + value + '</p>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="food-list">
  <div class="active Mango">
    <li>Mango</li>
    <select class="serving-size">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</ul>

<button class="submit-items">submit</button>
```

Comment: This should be working, but every time I run this I get this error:

jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .
           
                    
                    Mango

Comment: I'm not sure if this is because the toLowerCase() function isn't working, but I don't see how that can be the case. The function looks sound...

Comment: you have a space between `.` and `Mango` ?

Comment: Shouldn't be, I just pasted your exact code in. I'll keep trying to figure it out, thanks though.